# How to reveal sub-class methods in RubyMine IDE

Tags: ide, rubymine

While typing out a function or variable, rubymine will give a prediction and show available functions, but it only does this one-level deep.

```
class A
   attr_reader :b

   def initialize
      @b = B.new
   end
end

class B
   attr_reader :foo

   def bar
   end
end
```

Now if i make an object A and call b then I can't see its variables or methods.

```
test = A.new
test. #IDE prediction works and I see 'b'
test.b. #no prediction shows up after typing .
```

I'm not sure how other libraries are doing this. How do I expose foo and bar to the IDE? I have no issues with accessing them.

Comment: Probably because there is no instance method `b` in the `class A`; all you did was assign an instance variable. You need either a manual instance method or an `attr_reader` for `@b` if you want `test.b` to do anything.

Comment: @anothermh ill update the example, but my application does have an attr_reader for @b

Comment: I have removed [tag:ruby] tag since the question has nothing to do with ruby language itself.

Comment: Could you specify your RubyMine version? I've checked that in RubyMine 2019.2 EAP2 and got completion for `bar` method for example.